# spring application takes too long to start

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have a java application in which I'm using Spring and Hibernate frameworks. On my production environment, it would take too long (upto an hour) to start the application properly, as in, within 10 minutes. I could see the login page but if I try to login, it would just keep processing. Only after an hour or so, I would be able to login.

After some research I found that by default `hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults` is set to `true`, in which case it takes time, so I set it to `false`. Now my application is starting up quickly in my local system when I point it to production db to test. Even in test environment it performs as expected. But when I rolled it out to production, it worked fine initially but now it again is taking too long to start up.

Any idea how to approach it now?

**EDITED:** adding more details:
initial startup time is huge. once it is up then pages would load fine. we are using postgres db and have multiple schemas. Please suggest what other details are needed

Below is session factory onfiguration:

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="mydb"/>     
    <property name="entityInterceptor" ref="nullToEmptyStringInterceptor" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
       <props>
           <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</prop>
           <prop key="hibernate.multiTenancy">SCHEMA</prop>
           <prop key="hibernate.tenant_identifier_resolver">path_to.DataBaseResolver</prop>
           <prop key="hibernate.multi_tenant_connection_provider">path_to.MultiTenantProvider</prop>      
           <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
           <prop key="hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults">false</prop>
       </props>
    </property> 
    <property name="packagesToScan">
       <list>
           <value>path_to_model_package</value>            
       </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Below is entityManagerFactory configuration

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="mydb" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaVendorAdapter" />
    <property name="jpaDialect" ref="jpaDialect" />
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="myPersistenceUnit" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" >
        <list>
            <value>path_to_model_package</value>
        </list>
    </property>
     <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.use_get_generated_keys" >true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>

</bean>
```

Comment: How many bean files in your component scans?

Comment: all the packages are included in component-scan. this is an old application, people who worked before me have done this. i am not sure how much i must change it.

Comment: if you loading all the records from the database and showing in the UI can cause the issue, because obviously production has lot of records than local or test environment.
if it is the case, try to implement pagination kind of functionality to load limited records from the database

Answer (score 0):

I don't think we can tell you what the problem is.  It will be something to do what the applications is *doing* during startup, and we can only guess what that would be.

However ...

What you *should* do is to profile the application during startup, and use the profiling to identify where most of the time is being spent.  Then look to see if you can work out what it its doing ... and optimize it.

It would also be work turning on GC logging to see if memory usage / garbage collection is part of the problem.  Ditto for checking if database activity is a significant bottleneck.

Finally, an important step in finding the cause of this problem is likely to be understanding the internal architecture of the application.  Especially if this is code that has been passed from developer to developer over a number of years.

Answer (score 0):

As you did not posted full details of your problem, like hibernate, spring and other app configurations so suggesting you a solution is bit difficult. The following could be possibilities:

1. Somewhere there could be deadlock during application load time. For example, so batch job running in background before the container completely starts.
2. If your db schema is always checked to be updated after the container start and your db is having a large number of tables and columns with a lot of data inside then it would definitely take time before that application loading completes.
3. Check server configurations like if there is another instance of application running in parallel which is causing delay.